# JSF 4..2 - Missing Conversation Entry stacktrace

Tags: jboss, seam, ajax4jsf

I've seen posts that are directly related to my issue on jboss but the posts seem to be deleted or expired. Hoping someone has some insight..

I basically have a checkbox that changes the value of an object. The value persists fine but as soon as I navigate from the page, I get a big stack trace.

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{record.isChecked }" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <a:commandLink value="Checked?" style="text-decoration: none;color: #000000;" render="requests:requestTable" action="#{sortingBean.sortByStatus}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{record.isChecked}" onClick="this.form.submit();" valueChangeListener="#{requestList.onChangeChecked(record)}">
                <a:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this" listener="#{requestList.onChangeChecked(record)}"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </rich:column>


public void onChangeChecked(Request sRequest){

    sLog.debug("In onChangeChecked()...");

    if (sRequest.getIsChecked())
        sRequest.setChecked(false);
    else
        sRequest.setChecked(true);

    mEntityManager.merge(sRequest);
}
```

When I click on an item, which redirects me to another page, this is the method signature. Everything runs fine but at the end of the method, jboss dies.

```
@Begin(flushMode=FlushModeType.MANUAL, join = true)
public void selectRequest()
{ .......
```

The manual flushing is used for something else. I removed this and I get the same issue.

```
13:30:26,241 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] (http--127.0.0.1-443-6) swallowing exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing conversation entry
  at org.jboss.seam.core.Conversation.flush(Conversation.java:143) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.flushConversationMetadata(Manager.java:1054) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.prepareBackswitch(FacesManager.java:311) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:508) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:248) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:195) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
13:30:26,241 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] (http--127.0.0.1-443-6) swallowing exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing conversation entry
  at org.jboss.seam.core.Conversation.flush(Conversation.java:143) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.flushConversationMetadata(Manager.java:1054) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.prepareBackswitch(FacesManager.java:311) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:508) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:248) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:195) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.0.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

Comment: I also  just noticed that if I refresh the page, and then try to navigate elsewhere, the issue disappears.

Comment: It also seems like a new conversation is starting even thouhg I have join = true

Comment: anyone? would be nice to resolve this..

Comment: So I'm using these boolean checkboxes in similar ways elsewhere without issues. I'm thinking maybe it's because this is in a rich:datatable? Regardless, I need to be able to check/uncheck per row and have the immediately persist to bean.